# reading txt files in python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, text-files

I have a .txt file that contains the average price of BTC each day. Here are the contents of the btc.txt :

```
Date,Price
"Jun 06, 2018",7639.970
"Jun 05, 2018",7567.330
"Jun 04, 2018",7618.500
"Jun 03, 2018",7676.170
"Jun 02, 2018",7590.080
"Jun 01, 2018",7521.070
"May 31, 2018",7450.160
...
```

I have a list of dates and I want to find the average BTC value for each date in my list, so I tried this code:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv("btc.txt")
dates = calculating_date() #my list of dates 

initial_p = []
for item in dates:
    if(item != "N/A"):
        print (df[df["Date"] == item]["Price"])
        initial_p.append(df[df["Date"] == item]["Price"])
    else:
        initial_p.append(item)
```

However when I run it, I get this:

```
...
Name: Price, dtype: float64
111    9827.36
Name: Price, dtype: float64
48    8226.79
Name: Price, dtype: float64
16    8470.66
Name: Price, dtype: float64
26    8747.22
Name: Price, dtype: float64
68    7030.98
```

Rather than this:

```
...
9827.36
8226.79
8470.66
8747.22
7030.98
```

What can I change in my code to achieve the result above?

Comment: What's in the "dates" variable?

Comment: date = { ... "N/A", "Jun 04, 2016", "N/A", "N/A", "May 23, 2018", ...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value you can just do:

```
df[df["Date"] == item]["Price"].values[0]
```

Comment: I got this error: File "getICOdate.py", line 165, in <module>
    initial_price("btc.txt")
  File "getICOdate.py", line 159, in initial_price
    print (df[df["Date"] == item]["Price"].value[0])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3081, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'value'

Comment: Ah, it's values. My bad.

Comment: do you know what I can change?

Comment: Did ya try to change from value to values? I made a type and instead of .values I wrote .value.